# How to Hide or Show Custom attribute based on another custom attribute in Product detail/edit page from Adminpanel Magento 2.4.x?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I have created the Product's custom attributes programmaticaly (**Setup->Installdata.php**).

`

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'inquiry_attribute_enable',
            [
                'group' => 'Product Inquiry',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Enable',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'sort_order' => 10
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'inquiry_attribute_label',
            [
                'group' => 'Product Inquiry',
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Label',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'note' => 'Leave label as blank if you just want to hide price without having any inquiry button.',
                'sort_order' => 20
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'inquiry_attribute_allow_cart',
            [
                'group' => 'Product Inquiry',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Allow Add To Cart',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'sort_order' => 30
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'inquiry_attribute_disclose_price',
            [
                'group' => 'Product Inquiry',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Disclose Product Price',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'sort_order' => 40
            ]
        );

        // get default attribute set id
        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupName = 'Product Inquiry';

        // custom attribute group
        $eavSetup->addAttributeGroup(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeSetId,
            $attributeGroupName,
            100
        );

        // add attribute to group
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeSetId,
            $attributeGroupName,
            'inquiry_attribute_enable', // attribute code
            10
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeSetId,
            $attributeGroupName, // attribute group
            'inquiry_attribute_label',
            20
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeSetId,
            $attributeGroupName,
            'inquiry_attribute_allow_cart',
            30
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeSetId,
            $attributeGroupName,
            'inquiry_attribute_disclose_price',
            40
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

`

I want to Hide or Show a Custom attribute based on another custom attributes in the Product group

For example, there is a toggle on click (yes/no) button. when i click it it should hide or show **label**,  **Allow Add To Cart** and  **Disclose Product Price** fields.

[Screenshot of product attribute group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bijIp.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.4.x, you can hide or show a custom attribute based on another custom attribute in the product detail/edit page from the admin panel by using JavaScript and the jQuery library. Here are the basic steps to accomplish this:

1. Create a new JavaScript file in the

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/web/js

directory, for example

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/hide-show-custom-attribute.js

2. In the JavaScript file, use jQuery to listen for changes in the first custom attribute, and then use jQuery's show() or hide() functions to display or hide the second custom attribute based on the value of the first custom attribute:

```js
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#first_custom_attribute').on('change', function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'some_value') {
                $('#second_custom_attribute').show();
            } else {
                $('#second_custom_attribute').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

3. In your layout XML file "app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml" or "catalog_product_edit.xml" add the following code to load the JavaScript file in the admin product edit/detail page:

```html
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <head>
                <script src="[Vendor_Module]::js/hide-show-custom-attribute.js" />
            </head>
        </page>
```

4. Clear the cache and check the product detail/edit page in the admin panel, the second custom attribute should now be hidden or shown based on the value of the first custom attribute.

**Note:** *The above code snippet is only an example and may need to be adjusted to match the specific attribute codes and values of your custom attributes.*